# In oracle, how do I change my session to display UTF8?

Tags: oracle, utf-8

I can't figure out Oracle's encryptic syntax for the life of me.  This is Oracle 10g

My session's NLS_LANGUAGE is currently defaulting to AMERICAN.
I need to be able to display UTF8 characters.

Below are some of my attempts, all incorrect:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE='UTF8'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE='AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

What's the secret command?

Comment: Is your database configured to hold UTF8? What are the database NLS_LANG settings?

Comment: Yes, configured to hold UTF8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The character set is part of the locale, which is determined by the value of `NLS_LANG`.  As [the documentation makes clear](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#i1006330) this is *an operating system variable*:

> `NLS_LANG` is set as an environment
>   variable on UNIX platforms. `NLS_LANG`
>   is set in the registry on Windows
>   platforms.

Now we can use `ALTER SESSION` to change the values for a couple of locale elements, NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_TERRITORY.  But not, alas, the character set.  The reason for this discrepancy is - I think - that the language and territory simply effect how Oracle interprets the stored data, e.g. whether to display a comma or a period when displaying a large number.  Wheareas the character set is concerned with how the client application renders the displayed data.  This information is picked up by the client application at startup time, and cannot be changed from within.

Comment: My understanding of the WHY is different. The character set of the client has to be determined before the sql*net connection to the database is made so that the correct character set translations can be used.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, per http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/globalization/htdocs/nls_lang%20faq.htm:

> NLS_LANG cannot be changed by ALTER
>   SESSION, NLS_LANGUAGE and
>   NLS_TERRITORY can. However
>   NLS_LANGUAGE and /or NLS_TERRITORY
>   cannot be set as "standalone"
>   parameters in the environment or
>   registry on the client.

Evidently the "right" solution is, before logging into Oracle at all, setting the following environment variable:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

Oracle gets a big fat F for usability.

Comment: Is UTF8 the correct choice for windows?  Docs indicate that AL32UTF8 supersedes it and that there are no UTF-8 windows clients: "...UTF8 has been superseded by AL32UTF8. Do not use UTF8 for XML data." [1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/gblsupp.htm#BABDHCGD)  "if the database character set is AL32UTF8 and the client is running on a Windows operating system, then you should not set AL32UTF8 as the client character set in the NLS_LANG parameter because there are no UTF-8 WIN32 clients." [2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#i1006330)

Answer (score 3):

Therefore, before starting '$ **sqlplus**' on OS, run the followings:

- On Windows

  set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
- On Unix (Solaris and Linux, centos etc)

  export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8

It would also be advisable to set env variable in your '.bash_profile' [on start up script]

This is the place where other ORACLE env variables (ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME) are usually set.

just fyi - **SQL Developer** is good at displaying/handling non-English UTF8 characters.