# Oracle (PL/SQL) : Temporarily change character set

Tags: oracle, encoding, plsql

I have a csv file and two database (let's call them A and B). My goal is to insert data from csv file into the database B. However, I have to work in the environment of the database A.

The problem is that the character set of the database A makes me lose information (such as accents, I work with czech words). And the icing on the cake, I do not have the rights to change it. N character set doesn't help me further.

So, can I change the character set for just a pl / sql script?

**Database A**:

NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16

**Database B**:

NLS_CHARACTERSET = UTF8

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = UTF8

Comment: In general, set appropriate NLS_LANG environment variable before launching a script. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000243/232279) may help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it with PL/SQL. The Oracle documentation says it is not possible :( .

You can change the session language and character set by changing the registry (in Windows `HKLM\Software\Oracle\KEY_...\NLS_LANG`) to something like `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`.

This on the other hand does not affect the character set the database saves the data in.

Comment: Hello !
After your request, I obtain : 
     ORA-00922 : "missing or invalid option"
:/